# Некоторые свойства Sass не компилируются в Css

Tags: css, gulp, sass, scss

возникла такая проблема, что при компиляции sass файла в css некоторые свойства не компилируются (например:display или position). Пробовал через программу 'Prepros', и через gulp везде одно и тоже. Но при компиляции sccs файла в css все нормально. Не знаю в чем причина.

[image: вот и проблема]

Comment: А если старые свойства изменить, они скомпилируются? Подозреваю, что нет. Подозреваю, что тип компиляции изменён с sass на scss.

Comment: Если изменить старые то новые тоже изменятся. Не знаю почему но только определенные свойства не компилируются

Comment: А в gulpfile.js  у вас что написано?

Comment: const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('sass-compile', function() {
 return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(sass({outputStyle:'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function()  {
 gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass-compile'))
})

Comment: здесь gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')  и здесь gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss' я специально написал scss чтоб убедиться что на scss все в порядке

Comment: Так смените обратно на `gulp.src('./sass/**/*.sass')` и `gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.sass')`. Работает или один тип файлов, или другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда указываете ".sass" - работать будут файлы этого типа, если укажете ".scss" - то только такие файлы будут компилироваться, но не оба типа сразу.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'); 
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
gulp.task('sass-compile', function() {
    return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.sass') // или scss
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle:'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
})
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.sass', gulp.series('sass-compile')) // или scss
})
```